# what is Naur Text-Processing

Tags: algorithm

Can someone please explain to me in layman terms what the **Naur Text-Processing rules**? I'm having trouble understanding what the rules mean such as *line by line form* and *line breaks*.

Comment: Does it refer to an exercise? http://www.cse.msu.edu/~stire/435/Lectures/05aNaurSpec.pdf

Comment: yes it does refer to an exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that you have a text, say

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\nUt enim
>   ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

The text contains *three* kinds of characters:

1. Spaces ()
2. New Line characters (`\n`)
3. Letters (all other characters: letters, digits, punctuations...)

You have to *split* the given text into *lines* in the most efficient way (you want to obtain as few lines as possible), but the split must meet restrictions:

1. *New Line* character `\n` *must* start a new line
2. You *can* split text and start a new line on *space* only
3. Each line can contain *at most* `MaxPos` (given constant) characters.

In the sample above for `MaxPos = 30` we can split as

```
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consectetur adipiscing elit, 
   sed do eiusmod tempor 
   incididunt ut labore et 
   dolore magna aliqua.\n      <- \n New Line must break; we can't add "Ut" in the line
   Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   ...
```

These splits *broke* the rules and that's why are *invalid*:

```
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <- The line is too long, exceeds MaxPos = 30
   ...

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consectetur adipiscing elit, 
   sed do eiusmod tempor incidi <- wrong split: we can split on spaces only
   dunt
   ... 

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consectetur adipiscing elit, 
   sed do eiusmod tempor 
   incididunt ut labore et 
   dolore magna aliqua.\nUt enim <- \n (New Line) must start a new line
   ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
   ...
```

Comment: So we arent modifying the textfile we are just printing it out in a way that it meets the restrictions?

Comment: @CminusMinus: usually, *yes*: all we have to do is to print out. However, you may be asked to save the split in a file.